# macOS: I can't delete a file from Finder and it's not visible in the Terminal

Tags: macos, filesystem, error

I saw there are other similar questions here but I could not find an answer for my case. I have a file that I can't delete, that:

- it is visible in Finder
- and it is not in the Terminal

therefore I can't do anything from the Terminal.

I've tried restart, disk reboot/repair, rename, move, etc, but I always get:

*The operation can’t be completed because an unexpected error occurred (error code -50).*

macOS Monterey 12.3.1
MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021)

thanks

Edited: The file is in the default Downloads folder. File is something.pdf

Comment: What is the filepath and name of the file?

Comment: Is the file on an external disk? Have you tried First Aid in Disk Utility?

Comment: @benwiggy It's in the Downloads folder. And it's something.pdf

Comment: @Gilby It's not. Yes I've tried First Aid, but there wasn't anything to fix.

Comment: How did you look in the Terminal - What does `ls -lAB@ ~/Downloads` show?

Comment: @mmmmmm good tip. I can actually see the file now, at least the icloud version of it: .something.pdf.icloud

Comment: @mmmmmm ok solved. I was able to remove the icloud file from terminal, and the file disappeared in Finder as well.

Comment: In case it's not clear, by default `ls` treats files with names starting with a `.` as hidden. You need to specify `-a` or `-A` to show them. (Not just `ls`; it's a common convention on Unix-like systems — of which macOS is one.)